# JDOM Premature end of file exceptions?

Tags: java, jdom

I'd like to read all CDATA associated to a child node and store them into a java ArrayList! If you could suggest a simple and quick way I'd grately appreciate it!

In this code I try to check the child nodes for a matching "txid" attribute and store the CDATA under it into an ArrayList.  This code is initially suggested by "FloppyDisk" and I a just applied some modfications to it to fit my overall code!

```
 SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
 Document doc = builder.build(in);  //build a JDOM doc from an input stream
 ArrayList<String> queries = new ArrayList<String>();
 Element root = doc.getRootElement();

 Iterator elemIter = root.getDescendants();

 while (elemIter.hasNext()) {
     Element tempElem = (Element) elemIter.next();
     if (root.getChild("ZQueries").getAttributeValue("txid").equals(tempTxid)) {
         String CDATA = tempElem.getChildText("ZQueries");
         queries.add(CDATA);
     } 
 }



Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.security.PrivilegedActionException:
java.security.PrivilegedActionException: org.jdom.input.JDOMParseException: Error on 
line 1: Premature end of file.
```

AND Here's the XML structure

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
 <ZQueries txid="Group 1" version="1.0.0.0">
 <ZQuery name="Some Name 1" savename="SomeFileName1.xml">
  <![CDATA[ 
      SELECT ...........

  ]]> 
 </ZQuery>
 <ZQuery name="Some Name 2"   savename="SomeFileName.xml">
 <![CDATA[ 
    SELECT .............


  ]]> 
</ZQuery>
<ZQuery name="some name 3" savename="someFileName.xml">
<![CDATA[ 
    SELECT ..............

 ]]> 
 </ZQuery>
 </ZQueries>
 <ZQueries txid="Group 2" version="1.0.0.0">
 <ZQuery name="Some Name 1" savename="SomeFileName1.xml">
  <![CDATA[ 
      SELECT ...........

  ]]> 
 </ZQuery>
 <ZQuery name="Some Name 2"   savename="SomeFileName.xml">
 <![CDATA[ 
    SELECT .............


  ]]> 

 </ZQueries>
```

Comment: This does not seem to be a JDOM issue. The ´java.security.PrivilegedActionException´ says you are trying to do something you have no permission for. Maybe you are trying to read the file from an unsigned applet? See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html